# Heroku throws 403 forbidden after build with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, webpack

I have a problem with building my vuejs app on heroku after using my webpack config instead of simple using `vue-cli-service build`

package.json

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",

//before webpack I use this
//"build": "vue-cli-service build",
```

after build with webpack my heroku build the whole app properly and I have this:

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 92.6M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v69
remote:        https://someapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

but when i go to `https://someapp.herokuapp.com/`, my app is blank and I have `403 Forbidden nginx` :/

I do not know what is wrong with my webpack :/

here is my webpack config

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'someapp.bundle.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'someapp.bundle.css'
    }),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      algorithm: "gzip",
      filename: "[path][base].gz"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },{
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
    },{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
    },{
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'
    },{
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=./img/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=./img/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        use: ["file-loader?name=./img/[name].[ext]"]
    }, {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: ["file-loader?name=./img/[name].[ext]"]
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve('src')
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: false
}
```

@EDIT:
I change build to `vue-cli-service build` and whole app was created successfully and a I do not have 403:Forbidden, so, problem must be with webpack

can someone tell me what is wrong with my heroku build?

thanks for any help!

Comment: webpack can't cause a 403. You must have changed something else

Comment: but before using webpack config I use simple `vue-cli-service build` and all worked, but after using webpack build server respond with 403 forbidden ://